# Solve $a^n - b^n = 8$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}$.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I already solved the question myself, but there is something bottering me. In the exersice is told "Solve, by easy estimations". I couldnt find a boundary for $n$ or something. I started with $a^n = 8 + b^n$ and then follows $a \leq \sqrt[n]{8} + b$, so $a-b \leq \sqrt[n]{8}$. Knowing that $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ we find that for $n > 3 \implies a-b \leq 1$. But now $a$ and $b$ can be negative aswell. So it isn't a boundary yet. Hopefully help comes soon, otherwise i cant sleep..

Comment: If $n$ is even, negativeness doesn't matter. If $n$ is odd, and $a$ and $b$ are of different signs, that makes the absolute value of the difference big.

Comment: If $n\ge 4$ then every one-step difference of $x^n$ except from $-1$ to $0$ and $0$ to $1$ is at least $2^4-1^4=15$, which is too large. So only $n\in\{2,3\}$ need to be investigated.

Comment: Thanks Henning, so the boundary of $n$ is found by checking the one-step difference. Is 2^n - 1^n always the lowest one-step difference? If so i totally get it, thanks!

Comment: just a little tidbit, adding on to Henning's answer: for the case n=3, we can see that $2^3 + b^3 = a^3$ will not have any solutions due to fermat's last theorem

Comment: Smart use of fermat. Only thing left is n = 2, which is pretty easy and gives all solutions. Thanks guys!