# Diophantine equation $a^n-b^n=8$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I would like a hint for the following Diophantine equation:
$a^n-b^n=8$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 2}$.

I know this can be done with estimates, but all my tries led nowhere. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-is-an-bn-divisible-by-a-b

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564594/solve-an-bn-8-with-a-b-in-mathbbz-and-n-in-mathbbn-geq-2)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know it was already asked.

Comment: $a-b$ is a factor only factors of 8 are 1,2,4,8 .